# Gentoo GCC failed emerge

Tags: c, gcc, gentoo

i'm trying to resurrect an old installation of Gentoo Linux that has kernel 2.6.32 and i could update @system with an exception: gcc 4.5.4 failed installation.
The last lines are here:

http://pastebin.com/8s4z0FJy

Ask me if you need more info, i'll post something more when i get home (Got that info through SSH).
Even GHC fails compiling but i'll handle that later. I need GCC in order to compile the other packages.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When posting to SO, it is never good practice to refer readers to a link. You need to post all needed/relevant code/errors as part of your question. That being so, the relevant parts of **The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/gcc-4.5.4/temp/build.log'.** are needed before anyone can provide help. Superficially, it looks like either a bug in the gcc build script, or a permission problem. Why are you trying to `rebuild` gcc instead of simply `installing` gcc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To respond to a link with another link from googling: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-896518-start-0.html. Let me summarize that thread:

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:87553: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:88534: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.l38'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
xgcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
```

Basically, the assembly errors come because gcc’s assembly output was interrupted when it was killed. The Gentoo forums thread suggests this may likely be because gcc used up too much memory. You can confirm this by checking near the end of `dmesg`’s output for OOM stuff. If memory is not the issue, then you might have a real bug and should follow the instructions in the text you pastebined for reporting the bug to https://bugs.gentoo.org/. But, please try seeing if memory is the issue first.

If memory is the issue, make sure that you have swap partitions on your machine and that they are enabled. You can view a summary of your enabled swap partitions by running `swapon -s`. If nothing shows up and you cannot repartition, you can always use a trick like `# ( umask 0077 && dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swap.img bs=1M count=1024 && mkswap /.swap.img && swapon /.swap.img )` (the ‘#’ indicates a root shell prompt, so don’t actually type it). The forum thread also suggests that removing `-pipe`, which causes gcc to use more memory instead of writing out lots of temporary files, from `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` (by editing `/etc/make.conf` or `/etc/portage/make.conf`, whichever exists). We cannot tell what your `CFLAGS` are from what you posted.

Comment: Hi guys, i've tried to add 1GB of swap but the compilation failed anyway =(
Those are the last lines of build.log:
http://pastebin.com/QxEenHWS
and this is my make.conf:

CFLAGS="-O2 -pipe -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp"
CXXFLAGS="${CFLAGS}"
CHOST="armv7a-unknown-linux-gnueabi"
MAKEOPTS="-j2"
PORTDIR="/usr/portage"

Can't figure out what is the problem.. Any advice?

Comment: You're not including enough information in those pastes. It looks like you're getting a *different* error now that deserves its own question (no more `Killed` message, you are probably hitting a cross compilation or esoteric arch thing). Also, as these things are dependent on the various versions of each package involved, you might get better help from #gentoo or Gentoo's own forums.