# Installing lxml: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive

Tags: python, gcc, pip, lxml

I've been trying to install the Python library lxml but here is the output. I've spent the past half hour looking into dependencies but I don't think that's the problem.

I'm running this script on CentOS 6 with 512 MB RAM. It's a fresh server from Digital Ocean, and it has almost nothing running.

Full error log below.

```
# sudo pip install lxml
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-GiDliY/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0UHULP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.26
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    {standard input}: Assembler messages:
    {standard input}:26497: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
    {standard input}:26754: Error: no such instruction: `ca'
    {standard input}:26754: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    creating tmp
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInituswMfK.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInituswMfK.o
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInituswMfK.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-GiDliY/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0UHULP-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-GiDliY/lxml/
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically, the assembly errors come because gcc’s assembly output was interrupted when it was killed. The Gentoo forums thread suggests this may likely be because gcc used up too much memory. You can confirm this by checking near the end of dmesg’s output for OOM stuff. If memory is not the issue, then you might have a real bug and should follow the instructions in the text you pastebined for reporting the bug to https://bugs.gentoo.org/. But, please try seeing if memory is the issue first.

If memory is the issue, make sure that you have swap partitions on your machine and that they are enabled. You can view a summary of your enabled swap partitions by running swapon -s. If nothing shows up and you cannot repartition, you can always use a trick like

```
# ( umask 0077 && \
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swap.img bs=1M count=1024 && \
    mkswap /.swap.img && \
    swapon /.swap.img )
```

(the ‘#’ indicates a root shell prompt, so don’t actually type it). The forum thread also suggests that removing -pipe, which causes gcc to use more memory instead of writing out lots of temporary files, from CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS (by editing /etc/make.conf or /etc/portage/make.conf, whichever exists). We cannot tell what your CFLAGS are from what you posted.

see [Gentoo GCC failed emerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575756/gentoo-gcc-failed-emerge)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't have enough memory. I think you can enable use swap